# Long Long overflow

Tags: c, string, integer, atoi

I have been working on a small program that converts strings into integers.
I started the program and I was first trying to save in an array but the program is not working.
Its iterating only once and there is no error.I tried it but I think the error is at when I convert the string by subtracting it by 48 in storing it in the array.You can see the code

Sorry this is an edited message tnow the program is working properly but when I give input -"-91283472332"(as per leetcode) I am getting a wrong answer

you can see for yourself -
[image]

```
#include <stdio.h>

int myAtoi(char *s)
{
    int i = 0;           // for iterating the character
    int isNegative = 0; // for checking if the umber is negative
    long long res = 0;         // for result
    while (s[i] != '\0')
    {
    printf("%d\n",res);
        if (48 <= s[i] && s[i]<= 57)
        {
            res=(res*10)+(s[i]) - 48;
        }
        else if (s[i] == 45)
        {
            isNegative = 1;
        }
        else if (s[i] == ' ')
        {
            ;
        }
        else
        {
            break;
        }

        i++;
    }
    if (isNegative)
    {
        res = res-(res*2);
    }
    printf("%d",res);
    return res;
}



int main()
{
    char a[] = "-91283472332";
    myAtoi(a);
    return 0;

}
```

Comment: `if (48 <= s[i] <= 57)` doesn't do what you think it does and it is always true. `z` is also uninitialized. Turn up the warning level in your compiler and pay attention to them. https://godbolt.org/z/hYMGaKdWe

Comment: `int arr[5];` is too small for the input given so you write out of bounds

Comment: Using character literals like `'0'`, `'9'`, and `'-'` make things much easier to understand than having to memorize magic numbers.

Comment: `int z;` leaves `z` uninitialized

Comment: OT: The "isNegative" check should only be done on first character I would assume

Comment: Strongly suggest using [`isdigit`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/isdigit) to check if the current character is a digit.

Comment: Clearly there _is_ an error, just not one detected by the compiler.  Compilers can detect syntactic errors not _semantic_ errors.

Comment: Warnings are useful for detecting mistakes that may turn into unexpected behavior. Make sure to use them.

Answer (score 1):

Your solution is rather more complex than it needs to be.

We can use pointer arithmetic to iterate over the string, and include a condition for our for loop that automatically terminates at the end of the string *or* when the current character is no longer a digit.

The `result` can be built up by multiplying it by ten on each loop and adding the current digit's numeric value to it.

A negative sign can be accommodated by checking the first character. It's it's `'-'` we can set a flag `negative` to `1` for true and increment the `str` pointer past the first character. At the end of the  function, we can determine whether to result `-result` or `result` based on that flag.

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int my_atoi(char *str) {
    int result = 0;
    int negative = 0;    

    if (*str == '-') {
        negative = 1;
        str++;
    }

    for (; *str && isdigit(*str); str++) {
        result *= 10;
        result += *str - '0';
    }

    return negative ? -result : result;
}

int main(void) {
    char foo[] = "3456gfghd";

    printf("%d\n", my_atoi(foo));

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: How will this work for the given input `-91283472332`? It looks as though the result needs to be clamped to the range of `int` rather than be allowed to overflow.